# When extending ApplicationUsers, I get null error when trying to access properties

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to access properties in ApplicationUser.cs from Customer.cs class. I keep getting a null error. I get no errors until I run app and try to display all users. The error happens on ApplicationUser.BusinessName

Customer.cs

```
public class Customer
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
    public string CustomerUserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    public string BizName
    {
        get
        {
            return ApplicationUser.BusinessName;
        }

    }
 }
```

ApplicationUser.cs

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Organization")]
    public string BusinessName { get; set; }
    ....
 }
```

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

AdminUsers Controller

```
     public class AdminUsersController : Controller
         {
            private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
            private readonly RoleManager<ApplicationRole> _roleManager;
            private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

     public AdminUsersController(ApplicationDbContext db, RoleManager<ApplicationRole> roleManger, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
         {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _roleManager = roleManger;
        _db = db;
    }
  public async Task<IActionResult> Index Customer customer)
      {
          var users = from u in _userManager.Users.Include(u => u.Orders).Include(u => u.UserRoles).ThenInclude(ur => ur.Role) select u;

          return  View( users.Include(u => u.Customer).Include(u => u.Orders).ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));

       }
```

Comment: Have you verified that ApplicationUser exists? This is exactly the error I would expect if you attempted to access BusinessName when there's no ApplicationUser.

Comment: I verified that all Users in the DB have BusnessName and All Customers are linked to ApplicationUser. When I use a breakpoint and hover ApplicationUser.BusinessName applicationuser is null

Comment: @robert_rg did my answer resolve your issue?

Comment: Hi GregH, I solved it, I kept using breakpoints trying to figure out why my code in the method wasn't getting hit. Turns out it hit my Customer class first. This was due to passing "Customer customer" in the method as an argument. I just simply removed it. I didn't know that was there, Thats my mistake because it makes people think I'm trying to display all customers when I wanted all users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the child entities (`ApplicationUser`s in this case) when you query out your `Customer` object from the database.

i.e: for a querying a single `Customer` out of the db:

`_context.Customers.Include(x => x.ApplicationUser).Single(y => y.Id == myCustomerId)`

or for all/multiple:

`_context.Customers.Include(x => x.ApplicationUser).ToList();`

Without doing this, you'll see the exact symptoms you are noticing. The DB has valid data and valid foreign key associations however your complex child object is null despite having a valid foreign key (`CustomerUserId` in this case) after the data is queried out.

The null reference exception itself is a symptom of the above issue. The `ApplicationUser` is not included in the queried data so it remains null, you then try to access a property on a null object and that results in a null reference exception.

If you include your actual query for getting the `Customer`s in your post, then I can supply you with the actual updated query you need to include the `ApplicationUser` object on each `Customer` object.

Comment: Yeah, I still had another issue the way I thought I fixed it but changing it ToList vs selecting u fixed it. I tried it but I was just being lazy and didn't want to update my filters. Once I did that everything works perfectly

Comment: Any reason why it won't work on edit post method? I get the same error.

Comment: I'd recommend making another post as itll be a different issue you're having